# how I can assign for each UIImageView in the same view a picture taken from camera?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I have two UIImageView in the same view.for each imageView I should assign a picture taken from the camera or photos library.
When I start by doing that, I get the same photo for the two imageView.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    imageView2.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

} 


-(IBAction)addPhoto:(id)sender{

    UIActionSheet *actionSheet =[[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Choose Photo" otherButtonTitles:@"Take Photo ", nil];


    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];

}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    shouldUpdateFirstImage =YES;
    // chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

  if (shouldUpdateFirstImage) {
        imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
        shouldUpdateFirstImage = NO;
    }
    else {
        pictureView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

        shouldUpdateFirstImage = YES;
    }

}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if([title isEqualToString:@"Put Picture"])
    {
        alrtView.hidden = YES;
        pictureView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
       [self.view addSubview:pictureView];
        [self addPhoto:self];
    }
```

And the viewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIActionSheetDelegate,UITextViewDelegate>
{

    BOOL shouldUpdateFirstImage;

}
```

The first ImageView is the background.Through an AlertView I choose to add Picture to the first ImageView.After that I recall the same actionsheet to choose the taken photo.

Comment: Just assign the image to one of the image views instead of both.

Comment: And the second one?how can I do the difference between the two imageview??

Comment: You assign the second one when the user picks another image.

Comment: when the user picks another image,the first one will change.Can you please explain it to me more ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR  you need to track the state of your class, and have your delegate method respond accordingly to that state.

It sounds like you need your class to keep track of how many images have been displayed, and load new selections based on that information. We call this "state", and you have to implement the logic for your imagePickerController delegate method to respond appropriately to that state.

One possible approach would be to have a BOOL scoped to your class (either an ivar or property will do, but ivar is likely more appropriate), then use it's value to keep track of which imageView should be updated.

Assuming you already declared a BOOL named shouldUpdateFirstImage, you could do something like this:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

if (shouldUpdateFirstImage) {
        imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
        shouldUpdateFirstImage = NO;
    }
else {
    imageView2.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    shouldUpdateFirstImage = YES;
    }  
}
```

This would alternate which imageView was updated with each successive selection.

Comment: I tried that method but unfortunately I get the same image for the two UImageview.

Comment: did you scope the BOOL to your class or to your method? If it's scoped to the method, then it is being recreated each time and will not alternate.

Comment: I am sorry but I misunderstand you?I declare the BOOL in the .h then I assign shouldUpdateFirstImage =YES;

Comment: The variables you use to track state need to exist longer than your method call, so they are usually owned by the class. Then your method should behave differently based on the state. If you'd like us to help, post the code of where you create your state variables, and how you respond to them in the methods so we can see what you are doing

Comment: I find the issue thank you I just put  shouldUpdateFirstImage =YES in the viewdidload and it works fine thank you

Comment: glad it worked! You can do far more complex things with "state" than just a single BOOL, but you have the basic idea now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{
      [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

 if(imageView.image)
    imageView2.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
 else
    imageView.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

}
```

Comment: evaluating if(imageView.image) simply checks if the image property of your imageView exists. This will always return YES for an image view that does exist. That's why you need to use a state variable like a BOOL that you can keep track with.